# Replacing the deprecated https:outbound-endpoint with http:request in Mule

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, cxf, jax-ws

I was using the following configuration to hit a SOAP based service in mule 3.2, which works fine

```
<https:connector name="https" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"></https:connector>

<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" 
            address="https://localhost:8080/CXF3Service/test" responseTimeout="15000" contentType="application/xml" 
            doc:name="HTTP Submit Request SOAP" connector-ref="https"> <message-properties-transformer 
            scope="outbound"> <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="https://myservice/myEndpoint" 
            /> </message-properties-transformer> </https:outbound-endpoint>
```

[image]

SOAP Binding in wsdl will look like,

```
<wsdl:operation name="sayHello">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://myservice/myEndpoint" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="sayHello">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="sayHelloResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

On migrating to Mule 3.6, i replaced the code as follows. this was done to replace the deprecated https:outbound-endpoint with http:request

```
<http:request-config name="http" protocol="HTTPS"
        host="localhost" port="8080"
        doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>

<http:request config-ref="http" path="CXF3Service/test" method="POST"
            doc:name="HTTP" responseTimeout="15000" >
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:header headerName="SOAPAction" value="https://myservice/myEndpoint" ></http:header>
            </http:request-builder>         
            <http:success-status-code-validator
                values="0..599" />
        </http:request>
```

[image]

But on hitting the service with new code, i am getting a SOAP Fault as response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: https://myservice/myEndpoint, "".</faultstring>
      <detail/>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

FYI. I am using a cxf:proxy-client with payload as envelope, which remains unchanged for both.

```
<cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" doc:name="Proxy client">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor">
            <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
            <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
            <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
        </spring:bean>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:proxy-client>
```

Comment: The property was probably not mapped as an HTTP header when using the old transport. Could you add the proxy client part of the flow? The entire thing would be more helpful but that would help a lot.

Comment: proxy client part is added. it was added as a message property
<message-properties-transformer 
            scope="outbound"> <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="https://myservice/myEndpoint" 
            /> </message-properties-transformer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small tweak did the magic!!

I set the SOAPAction before the http:request instead of setting it inside.

```
<cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" doc:name="Proxy client">
<cxf:inInterceptors>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor">
        <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </spring:bean>
</cxf:inInterceptors>
<cxf:outInterceptors>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
        <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </spring:bean>
</cxf:outInterceptors>
<cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor">
        <spring:property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </spring:bean>
</cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:proxy-client>
```

> ```
>   <message-properties-transformer>
>       <add-message-property key="SOAPAction" value="https://myservice/myEndpoint"/>
>     </message-properties-transformer>
> ```

```
    <http:request config-ref="http" path="CXF3Service/test" method="POST"
        doc:name="HTTP" responseTimeout="15000" >        
        <http:success-status-code-validator
            values="0..599" />
    </http:request>
```